# How can i create an editable table column in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = "<table id='tblItemList'>" +
                   "<tr>" +
                       "<th style='width:20px;'>&nbsp;</th>" +
                       "<th style='width:100px;'><b>ItemId</b></th>" +
                       "<th style='width:100px;'><b>Item</b></th>" +
                       "<th style='width:100px;'><b>Quantity</b></th>" +
                   "</tr>";

    $("#ddlItemID").dropdownchecklist({forceMultiple: true , onComplete: function (selector) {
    var values = "";
    for (i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++) {
        if (selector.options[i].selected && (selector.options[i].value != "")) {
            if (values != "") values += ";";
            values += selector.options[i].value;

            var chkId = 'chkId' + i;
            var itemId = 'itemId' + i;
            var ItemName = 'ItemName' + i;
            var qty = 'qty' + i;

            var itemData = "<tr>" +
                           "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" + chkId + "' /></td>" +
                           "<td id='" + itemId + "' class='selectedItemId'>" + selector.options[i].value + "</td>" +
                           "<td id='" + ItemName + "' class='selectedItemName'>" + selector.options[i].text + "</td>" +
                           "<td id='" + qty + "' class='selectedItemQty'>" + 0 + "</td>" +
                       "</tr>";
            table += itemData;
        }
    }

    table += "</table>";
    $("#trItemsList").show();
    $("#trItemsList").html(table);
}
, onItemClick: function (checkbox, selector) {
    var justChecked = checkbox.prop("checked");
    var checkCount = (justChecked) ? 1 : -1;
    for (i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++) {
        if (selector.options[i].selected) checkCount += 1;
    }
    if (checkCount > 3) {
        alert("Limit is 3");
        throw "Too many items were selected";
    }
}
    });
});
</script>
```

I have the above jQuery code that creates an a table listing items selected from a dropdownchecklist that supports multiple select.

After a user has selected items in the dropdownchecklist, on onComplete, a "mini" table is created just below the dropdownchecklist with the users selected items.

Currently, the created table is read-only but what i want to achieve is the user to proceed and update the created tables last column (Quantity) with a numeric value for each item (row) in the table.

For example, if i selected Item_one, Item_five & Item_twenty from the dropdownchecklist, a table of 3 rows will be created. In that table i will have values for Item_ID and Item_Name. Now i want to be able to edit that table and input Item_Quantity against each row, after which i will finally save to the database.

Does any one how i can modify the above code such that the table created has an editable third column (Quantity), that users can update?

Below is the html for the dropdownlist

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownList("ddlItemID", ViewBag.GatePassItemsList as SelectList, new { @multiple = "multiple" })
</td>
```

Comment: What kind of dropdownlist you are using. I mean you are creating it from any plugin.? please provide html if possible. Because I am seeing an event dropdownchecklist..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, i have added the dropdownlist html

Comment: Ok. Checking on it..

Comment: can you provide all the js reference files you have referred in your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there you go!!

Jus replace your last `td` in itemData with below

```
'<td id="' + qty + '" class="selectedItemQty"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter quantity" id="txt_'+qty+'"></td>'
```

That's it.

Let me know if you face any issues!!